# MongoDB How to define a query for find an object in array, but the array exist of Object references

Tags: mongodb

Basically what I want to do is that I have an ObjectId of a `qr`. I want to use that ObjectId to find out which `qrBlock` does it belong. Im leaving my dbmodel [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st1Yb.png)
so you can track easily.

```
qrRoute.post("/scanQr", (req, res) => {
  let { data } = req.body;
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data);
  Qr.findById(id)
    .exec()
    .then((qrr) => {
      QrBlock.find({ qr: { "qr.$": id } }, (qrblck) => {
        console.log(qrblck);
      });

      
    });
});
```

I tried this code above it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QrBlock.findOne({ qr: { $all: [qrr._id] } })
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

did you try this way

```
qrRoute.post("/scanQr", (req, res) => {
  let { data } = req.body;
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data);
  Qr.findById(id)
    .exec()
    .then((qrr) => {
      QrBlock.find({ qr: id }, (qrblck) => {
        console.log(qrblck);
      });

      
    });
});
```